# creat empty array of strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

My app gets strings of images url from server and saves them in  an array .the problem is number of images url is not constant so i want to create empty array of strings and its size determined according to input entered to it .
i used this `Strings images=new Strings[5]` and i want thing like that `Strings images=new Strings[]` so how i can do that this is part of my code

```
 String[] images4=new String[3];
    String[] images5=new String[3];
    String[] images7=new String[3];
    String[] images6=new String[3];
    String[] images1=new String[3];
    String[] images2=new String[3];
    String[] images3=new String[3];
    String[] totals=new String[3];
  try {


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Content);
            JSONArray jre = json.getJSONArray("projects");
            JSONArray jreimages = json.getJSONArray("screenshots");
            mArrayList = new ArrayList<Projects>();

            for (int j = 0; j < jre.length(); j++) {

                mProduct = new Projects();
                JSONObject jobject = jre.getJSONObject(j);
                String name11 = jobject.getString("name");
                String description = jobject.getString("description");
                String status = jobject.getString("status");
                String version = jobject.getString("version");
                String id =jobject.getString("id");

                mProduct.setyourText(name11);
                    mProduct.setyourstatu(status);
                    mProduct.setYourversion(version);
                    mProduct.setyourdescription(description);

                      int k=0;
                int l=0;
                int o=0;
                int p=0;
                int w=0;



                    for (int i = 0; i < jreimages.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jjobject = jreimages.getJSONObject(i);
                        String imageid=jjobject.getString("project_id");

                        if (imageid.equals(id)) {
                            String urlimage = jjobject.getString("screenshot");
                            String total = url + urlimage;
                           // mess.setText(total);
                            if (imageid.equals("105")){
                                images1[k] = total;
                                k++;
                                totals=images1;
                            }
                           else if (imageid.equals("106")){
                                images2[k] = total;
                                k++;
                                totals=images2;
                            }
                            else if (imageid.equals("107")){
                                images3[k] = total;
                                k++;
                                totals=images3;
                            }
                              else if (imageid.equals("108")){
                                images4[k] = total;
                                k++;
                                totals=images4;
                            }
                            else if (imageid.equals("109")){
                                images5[k] = total;
                                k++;
                                totals=images5;
                            }
                            else if (imageid.equals("110")){
                                images5[k] = total;
                                k++;
                                totals=images5;
                            }
                            else if (imageid.equals("111")){
                                images6[k] = total;
                                k++;
                                totals=images6;
                            }
                            else{
                                totals=images7;
                            }
                      }

                }

                mProduct.setYourimages(totals);
                mArrayList.add(mProduct);
                mProduct = null;

            }
```

Comment: And you can't use a proper type for unknown final sizes, like `List` (`ArrayList`), because?

Comment: create array once you know the size. Declare as `String[] images5;`. Then create it once you know the size `images5 = new String[size]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create individual string array.You can use Arraylist to make a dynamic String array.

```
ArrayList<String> images =new ArrayList<String>();
```

to insert values.Just use add() method.
For example,You want to store iamgeUrls then :

```
images.add(image1);
images.add(image2);
```

And to retrieve data use get() method.Example :

```
images.get(position); //where position is the index of imageUrl you want to retrieve.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two approaches:

1. `String[] arr;`
2. `ArrayList<String> arrList= new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String[] array= new String[0];
```

Or

```
ArrayList<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();
```